# Wordpress numeric character after inner page?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having an issue on all of my Wordpress sites. Numeric characters after the inner page URLs, like `http://domainname.com/about-us/123452345/`, should display a 404 page error but they display the page on `http://domainname.com/about-us/`.

Is there a way to make it show the 404 page.

I tried `domainname.com/about-us/asdfasdfas` and it shows the 404 page which is great. but using numbers causes it to display the page.

---

Update:

I tried this in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^about-us/[0-9]+/?$ /doesnotexists.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about wordpress, but if you want to fix this via htaccess rules, try this (make sure that `doesnotexists.php` does not realy exists so that it throws a 404 header) :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about-us/[0-9]+/?$ /doesnotexists.php [L]
```

Comment: where did you put it ? where does you htaccess reside ? did you check that mod_rewrite is enabled ? hwat else do you got in your htacces ? ...

Comment: my .htaccess is on the root directory of my wordpress file. I have updated my first post wherein i have put the current .htaccess code.